# Access Table Number Field with Input Mask returns inconsistent values in queries

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

tblTasks:
RepID : Number : Input Mask : "REP"00000;;_

When I perform a simple query on this field

select RepID from tblTasks

I get results like this:

```
RepID:
1234
REP1235
REP2345
2346
REP3457
```

Why isn't the input mask being applied consistently for all rows?

This make it impossible to perform like matches like so

select cStr(tblTasks.RepID) As RepId from tblTasks Where cStr(tblTasks.RepID) like "2*"

returns this:

```
RepID:
REP1235
REP2345
2346
REP3457
```

Instead of just 1 row (2346)

What is wrong here?

Requested Screen shot of properties:

[image]

Comment: That input mask is not saving the "REP" text part. Apparently some data has otherwise been entered so that the "REP" has been saved. However, having said that, the query should only match numbers that begin with "2", which would be 2345 and 2346.

Comment: How can that be when it is a numeric NUMBER field?

Comment: The mystery deepens. Why do some show the REP and some don't?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the table design with the RepID field selected, so we can see it's properties

Comment: The problem turned out to be the associated lookup table (tblRep) that at one stage was bound to the ID (numeric) of the that table but has now being bound to the Rep (string) .  I have no idea what data is actually being stored in that field?!?!?! I have recreated this is a small example DB and it is possible to bind a string field from a lookup table to a numeric field (with no complaints from Access regarding type mismatches).  I will start another thread regarding this problem!